# Theorem? Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets and $A \subseteq B \cup C$. Then either $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Theorem? Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets and $A \subseteq B \cup C$. Then either
$A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq C$.

Proof. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. Since $A \subseteq B \cup C$, it follows
that either $x \in B$ or $x \in C$.
Case $1.$ $x \in B$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A$, it follows that
$\forall x \in A(x \in B)$, which means that $A \subseteq B$.
Case $2.$ $x \in C$. Similarly, since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A$, we
can conclude that $A \subseteq C$.
Thus, either $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq C$.

Comment: The worng step is "Since x was an arbitrary element of A, it follows that ∀x ∈ A(x ∈ B)"... It can be that for $x_1 \in A$, from $A \subseteq B \cup C$ we have that $x_1 \in B$, and that for $x_2 \in A$, we have $x_2 \in C$ ...

Comment: I am still confused... Since an arbitrary element of A has the property of being in B or C doesnt it mean that all of the elements have that property?

Comment: Consider the case where $A$ overlaps with some of $B$ and some of $C$ but is not contained in either.

Comment: There may *exist* an $x \in A$ such that $x\in B$ but not C and there may exist another $x\in A$ such that $x \in C$, but not $B$. In this case, we have two elements of A, one in B (and not in C), the other in C (and not B), $A$ cannot be a subset of either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logic, the following inference is not valid :

1) assume $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds

2) from 1) infer that $\forall xP(x)$ holds.

Example : if we assume that $x=0$, we cannot conclude with $\forall x(x=0)$.

Thus, in the "argument" above, we assume that $x \in A$; thus (correctly) we have that $x \in B$ **or** $x \in C$.

Now, consider $x \in B$ ... but we **cannot** conclude that $x \in B$, for all $x$.

Consider $A = \{ 1,2,3 \}, B = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $C = \{ 3,4 \}$. Clearly : $A \subseteq B \cup C$ but **not** $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq C$.

---

See [Universal generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) : your case is a deduction with "assumptions" :

> $x \in A \vdash x \in B$.

The rule is :

> Assume $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas, $\varphi$ a formula, and $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(x)$ has been derived. The generalization rule states that $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi(x)$ can be derived **if** $x$ does not occur *free* in $\Gamma$ nor in $\varphi$.

In your example, $\Gamma = \{ x \in A \}$, and thus $x$ is *free* in it; so, we cannot "generalize" it to conclude with : $\forall x (x \in B)$.

Comment: I know why the theorem is wrong and i myself found a couple of counterexamples. However the author of the book which i saw this from (how to prove it) states that if we declare a variable to be arbitrary and infer a property of it(x ∈ B) then we can conclude the same property for the all of the objects within that statement. Otherwise if x wasnt arbitrary as it is stated to be i would agree that we cannot conclude that its properties are held by the rest of the members of the set. Sorry for the long comment.

Comment: @Александър Гьорев - but $x$ is **not** "declared arbitrary"; it is "declared" $x \in A$ ... See my example with $x=0$ : $x$ is not arbitrary, but it is assumed to be $0$; thus we cannot conclude that the property : "to be equal to $0$" holds for all $x$.

Comment: Look at the first sentence of the proof. "Let x be an arbitrary element of A". Otherwise i completly agree.

Comment: @Александър Гьорев - but nevertheless, if the "inference rule" licences us to derive a false conclusion (and it seems to me that you have to agree that the conclusion is false), then we have to conclude that the "purported rule" is not sound. I think that you have to review the [Universal generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) rule, in order to understand the two different way it can be used.

Comment: yeah it makes sense that way

Comment: @АлександърГьорев The separation into disjoint cases invalidates the arbitariliness.  You are no longer handling just any $x$, you have made a selection.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where A overlaps with some of B and some of C but is not contained in either.

That is, $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$, and $A\cap C \neq \varnothing$, but also $A\setminus B \neq \varnothing, $ and $A\setminus C \neq \varnothing.$

Answer (score 2):

> Proof. Let x be an arbitrary element of A. Since A ⊆ B ∪ C, it follows that either x ∈ B or x ∈ C. Case 1. x ∈ B. Since x was an arbitrary element of A, it follows that ∀x ∈ A(x ∈ B), which means that A ⊆ B. Case 2. x ∈ C. Similarly, since x was an arbitrary element of A, we can conclude that A ⊆ C. Thus, either A ⊆ B or A ⊆ C.

Let's examine this by way of analogy.

All cars on this highway will come to a fork in the road leading either east up to the mountains or west down to the coast.   So any car may go up to the mountains or down to the sea (by UI).   Case 1: We can follow a car that goes up to the mountains, therefore all cars go up to the mountains (by UG).   Case 2: We can follow a car that goes to the coast, therefore all cars go up to the coast (by UG).   In conclusion, the coast is up in the mountains!

... no?

---

You have attempted to use Universal Instantiation to make claims about an *arbitrary* $x$ so you might then use Universal Generalisation.   Where you go wrong with this is in splitting the claim into disjoint cases.

Once you partition the claim, you *cannot* then use universal generalisation on each separate case.   Like cars that come to a fork in the road, the $x$ in each case is no longer arbitrary; you've made a selection.   Some may satisfy one case, and some may satisfy the other, but it's not necessarily so that all satisfy both cases at once.